# Fourier transform of $\sin(x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am asked to compute the fourier transform of the distribution $f(x) = \sin (x) \ x \in \mathbb{R}$

> Let $L \in S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The fourier transform of $L$ is the map $\hat{L}: S(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{C}$ definied by $\hat{L} \psi := L \hat{\psi}$ $ \forall \psi \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

But I dont understand how I should "solve" for $\hat{L}$

$$
S(\mathbb{R}^n) := \{\psi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C} : \psi \text{ smooth }, \|\psi \|_{a,b} := \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |x^b D^a \psi(x)| < \infty \ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N} \cup {0} \} \\
a = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) \\
b = (b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n) \\
x^b = (x^{b_1}, x^{b_2}, \dots , x^{b_n}) \\
D^a \psi(x) = \frac{\partial^{a_1}}{\partial_{x_1}^{a_1}} \dots \frac{\partial^{a_1}}{\partial_{x_n}^{a_n}} \psi(x) \\
S'(\mathbb{R^n}) := \{L :S(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{C} : L \text{ Linear, Continuous } \}
$$

My attempt.

$$
FT(\delta) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta (x) e^{-ikx} dx = e^0 \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta (x) dx = 1.
$$

Thus
$$
FT(\delta (x-a)) = e^{-ika}
$$

Then

$$
\delta (x-a) = FT^{-1} (e^{-ika}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{ik(x-a)} dx.
$$

Thus

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin x e^{-ikx} dx = \frac{1}{2i} ( \delta (k-1) - \delta (k+1)).
$$

Comment: The Fourier transform is continuous and unitary $S(\mathbb{R}^n) \to S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so it is continuous and unitary $S'(\mathbb{R}^n) \to S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ too, i.e. $\delta$ is the FT of $1$

Comment: What is unitary? @user1952009

Comment: The Fourier transform $FT$ is a continuous linear operator $S(\mathbb{R}^n) \to S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and it is unitary : $FT^{-1} = FT^*$ (the adjoint). And as you know $(FT^* \varphi)(x) =  (FT \varphi)(-x)$

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to need more help. @user1952009

Comment: Is it clear to you that $FT(\delta) = 1$ ? Then what is $FT[\delta_a]$ ?

Comment: I mean somewhat it is clear because I know $FT(\delta) = \int \delta(x)e^{ikx} dx = e^{0} \int \delta (x) dx = 1 \cdot 1 = 1.$ @user1952009

Comment: And you need to prove $FT[\delta] = 1$ computed this way is compatible with the  definition $\forall \varphi \in S(\mathbb{R}), \langle FT[\delta],\ \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta, FT[\varphi] \rangle$

Answer (score 5):

The distribution $\sin(x)$ is
$$
      S(f) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\sin(x)dx, \;\;\; f\in\mathscr{S}.
$$
The Fourier transform of $S$ is defined by
$$
       \hat{S}(f) = S(\hat{f})= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(s)\sin(s)dx,\;\;\; f\in\mathscr{S}.
$$
The above is simplified by using the Fourier transform inversion:
\begin{align}
    \hat{S}(f) & = \left.\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(s)\frac{e^{isx}-e^{-isx}}{2i}ds\right|_{x=1} \\
     & = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2i}(f(1)-f(-1)) \\
     & = -i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\delta_{1}(f)-\delta_{-1}(f))
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
        \hat{S} = -i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\delta_1 -\delta_{-1})
$$